# Twilio conference call live streaming in website

Tags: twilio, live-streaming, twilio-php, twilio-api

Hi everyone, 
            I am new to the Twilio API. I have successfully setup call conferencing and recording. But my requirement is to stream live conference call from website. Is it possible...? I have been searching in google from 2 days but no use. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't exactly stream a conference call, but you could use [Twilio Client to provide a way for users on a website to dial into the conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js). You can then mute all of those callers so they are effectively just listening.

[Do note that you can only get 40 participants on a call using Conference and up to 250 using Global Conference](https://www.twilio.com/voice/conference).

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I can make call from browser and listen to live conference.

Comment: Twilio is not a live streaming service.

Comment: It is not, but if this conference based thing works, then I'm happy!

Comment: He should use one client to dial into conference then use the audio output of that client as source for streaming. Real live streaming on Internet is a bit more complex.